# select query within for loop first time run second time can not run

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql select query within for loop. it runs first time perfectly but second time not run. returns empty array. please check my code.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $looptime; $i++) {

     $text = array();
     $feedback_id = array();
     if ($i != 0) {
        $start = ($i * 100) + 1;
     } else {
        $start = $i * 100;
     }

     if ($i == $looptime - 1) {
        $end = $start + ($totalrecords - $start);
     } else {
        $end = ($i + 1) * 100;
     }

     $selquery= "select * from table where id >= $start and id <= $end";
     $res = mysqli_query($link,$selquery);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

     }
}
```

select query returns records when 1st first time loop. after that it returns blank array. please help to solve

Comment: Where is `$ext` defined? Please provide your form markup. Please mention what _is_ happening and what you _expect_ to happen so we don't have to parse and run stuff in our heads.

Comment: please check i have edit question

Comment: @shingalasohil the first iteration selects where id is between 0 and 100. Are you sure in your table you have ids higher than that range?